# String compare to literal java == interned string

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String m1 = args[0];
    System.out.println(m1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(args[0].hashCode());
    System.out.println("2345".hashCode());
    System.out.println(m1 == "2345");
}
```

If args[0] is "2345".
The output is 
1540226
1540226
1540226
false.
Why false? Interned string can be compared with ==, right?

Comment: Try `"2345".equals(m1)`

Comment: You can compare Strings with `==`, but it compares their identities, not values.

Comment: Strings passed as arguments are not interned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @MattClark No, it's not. The OP is displaying an understanding of the difference between `==` and `equals`, and the role that interning has to play. They're just asking about a specific aspect of that.

Comment: @yshavit, read the very first line of the accepted answer. `== tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).` This answers this question, ergo, duplicate.

Comment: Generally speaking: always assume `==` with `Object`s is _out to get you._

Comment: @MattClark But "Close as duplicate" means "This **question** has been asked before and already has an answer." This question is substantially different from that one, ergo not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Interned strings can only be compared using == to other interned strings, and will only return true if the interned string value is the same, ie

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String a2 = "a";
String c = a;
String d = a;


a == a2; //true
a == "a"; //true
a == new String("a"); //false
c == d; // true;
(a + a) == "aa"; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking a reference with value ?
"2345".equals(m1) is right.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is an object, so when you use `==`, you're not checking for value equivalency, you're checking if one String object is in the same memory location as another.

Use `.equals()` when you want to test for value equivalency between objects

Answer (score 1):

Just because one instance of a string is interned, doesn't mean that others are. In this case, `"2345"` is a string constant and is thus automatically interned, but there's nothing that requires the JVM to automatically intern the arguments to `main`. To my knowledge, there's nothing that explicitly prohibits the JVM from doing that, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: This answer solves my problem. Only literal strings are interned, args are not

Answer (score 0):

By  "==" you are checking and comparing "reference" values of the String.  Using "equals" works to compare the "contents" of two given strings.

hashCode returns similar values for m1, args[0], and "2345" because as interned strings, these have similar reference values as shown in your SOPs. Using a code example, this is how it is initializing:

```
String someString = "string_info"  
//Interning. Constant pool is checked for "string_info" and the reference is assigned to someString variable if "string_info" is found in constant pool.
```

However, when string is being passed as an argument, this is actually being created as a new string object. The new object is created in memory and hence your code  m1 == "2345" returns false. Using example, this is how it is initializing:

String someString = new String("string_info") //a new String object is first created in memory and then assignment of "string_info" is referenced using constant pool look up.